# Spark SQL optimal configurations for a single node process?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

We're using Spark SQL's great in memory sql functionality to join and parse some local data files before uploading them elsewhere. While we're happy with the functionality, we'd like to tweak the configs to squeeze some extra performance out.

We don't have a cluster, but will likely have 5 individual nodes all streaming files from S3, parsing them(they don't rely on any other external files) separately, and uploading them. Unfortunately we're using the Java api.

These are the configs I'm experimenting with, and any help would be awesome.

```
(Every RDD is being cached)
spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed    true
spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize 20000(doubled)
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold    10485760 
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions    10(since its a local process, reducing from 200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the following property as well which will make sure that the batches get pruned based on its columns statistics when a query is fired :-

```
spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.partitionPruning true
```

Note - This is the property name as far as Spark 1.2 is concerned. For 1.1, I remember that property name is a bit different. Please check the same if you are using 1.1.

Comment: Thank you! This has really sped up my process by roughly 30~50%. Is there a resource that goes deeper into what the pruning does? Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure about resource but you can check Spark's source code specifically following class and other revolving classes :-
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/columnar/InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala#L297